# Removing what ever string of word or words come after a special char █ on a single line

Tags: php, arrays, string, delimiter

I have a source file that file that contain to be translated strings. Each line of the translation cache files containt a `Source string` then a delimiter/separatpr `█` then the `translated string`

The original old author did write a nice clean up script that cleans the cache files from duplicates or deletes entire lines from the cache if the old source did not use them anymore.

Now I would like to add one more function into that existing code (relevant part below) which is : to delete the entire line when there is absolutely nothing `''`  coming after the separation key  `█` for the same line that its examining.

I have the feeling it will be 1 line of code somewhere below. But where how does this line look like?
Your help is much appreciated. Thanks very much in advance.

*CURRENT CACHE FILE:*

```
Bla blaaaa bla blaa blaaaaa bla█Bla blaaaa bla blaa blaaaaa bla
Zorro in zeppelin from zimbabwe█
Bla blaaaa bla blaa blaaaaa bla█Bla blaaaa bla blaa blaaaaa bla
Water wave with whistling whale█
```

*MY GOAL CACHE FILE:*

```
Bla blaaaa bla blaa blaaaaa bla█Bla blaaaa bla blaa blaaaaa bla
Bla blaaaa bla blaa blaaaaa bla█Bla blaaaa bla blaa blaaaaa bla
```

*EXISTING CODE:*

```
$translation_key_value_separator = '█';

// Read file contents and create a used keys array
$used_keys = array();
get_used_keys($dir_to_clean, &$used_keys);

// Cleanup translations: removes an entire line from the translation cache file 
// if the LEFT part of the █ is not existend (anymore) in the source files.
$removed = array();
$counter = 0;
foreach (glob($dir_translation_files . "/*.$translation_ext") as $filepath) {
    $filename = get_filename($filepath);
    $key_values = explode("\n", file_get_contents($filepath));
    $clean_file = array();
    foreach($key_values as $key_value){
      list($key, $value) = explode($translation_key_value_separator, $key_value);
      if($key != ''){
        if(in_array($key, $used_keys)){
            $clean_file[] = $key . $translation_key_value_separator . $value;
        }else{
            $removed[$filename][] = $key;
            $counter++;
        }
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you need to add another conditional when checking whether to add the line to `$clean_file` or `$removed`.  Please see the portion I extracted below:

```
if ($key != '') {
    if (in_array($key, $used_keys) && ($value != '')) {
        $clean_file[] = $key . $translation_key_value_separator . $value;
    } else {
        $removed[$filename][] = $key;
        $counter++;
    }
}
```

where the extra condition is `($value != '')`.

Comment: thanks looks very promising but I don't understand or you are incredibly genius, either of two :) please explain how your addon `&& ($value != '')` solves that `if the right part of the █ is empty` then `remove that entire line`? Thanks

Comment: @Sam, looking at the inner for loop the first line `list($key, $value) = explode($translation_key_value_separator, $key_value);` splits the line into two parts `$key` (the part before the separator) and `$value` (the part after the separator).  In the next few lines of code there is a check to see if the line should be added to the `$clean_file` or `$removed`.  Adding the condition `($value != '')` removes the line if the right part of the separator is empty.

Comment: BINGOOOOO now I understand! (before I did not) and therefore I am   JIPPIIEEEE   thanks very much mate!

Answer (score 1):

```
$cache = "Bla blaaaa bla blaa blaaaaa bla█Bla blaaaa bla blaa blaaaaa bla
Zorro in zeppelin from zimbabwe█
Bla blaaaa bla blaa blaaaaa bla█Bla blaaaa bla blaa blaaaaa bla
Water wave with whistling whale█"; 

$lines = explode("\n", $cache);
foreach($lines as $line){
    $x = explode("█", $line);
    if(!empty($x[1])) $new[] = $line;
}

print_r($new);
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Bla blaaaa bla blaa blaaaaa bla█Bla blaaaa bla blaa blaaaaa bla
    [1] => Bla blaaaa bla blaa blaaaaa bla█Bla blaaaa bla blaa blaaaaa bla
)
```

You can `$new = implode("\n", $new);` to get string instead of array.